# Writing a function that takes two integers and outputs the result of different applied operators

Tags: python, string, arguments

first post here. I have recently started to learn python and I have been trying to solve this menial task for two hours now, searches included.

What i wish to do is write a function that take two arguments (integers) and gives the result of the classic four operators. I will show you what I have done so far, and the not acceptable solution I did find.

## First attempt, only getting the first return value

```
def classicoperations(a, b):
return a + b
return a * b
return a / b
return a - b

print "Let's use the four classic operations"

print classicoperations(53, 100)
```

on the other hand, using just print it seems to work quite well

```
def classicoperations(a, b):
print a + b
print a * b
print a / b
print a - b

print "Let's use the four classic operations one more time"

classicoperations(5, 100)
```

How I would prefer for it to look as an end result, but that I for some reason cannot get to work properly and I am not sure as to why.

While the print makes the program lose the information, I cannot seem to make the function with "return" keep track of four different values nor how to separete them into a a combined string. Any help, even just a link as to what kind of understanding I am lacking will be greatly appreciated.

```
def classicoperations(a, b):
print "adding" a "to" b "be would create a total of" a+b

classicoperations(234324, 34324)
```

Comment: You must INDENT your return and print statements!!!  In your examples, return and print statements are not inside your def blocks.

Answer (score 2):

A return statement stops execution of the function. If you want to return multiple values, do it with one return:

```
return a+b, a-b, a*b, a/b
```

This creates and returns a tuple of 4 values.